# In Android, how do you programmatically access a user's default mapping application?

Tags: dictionary, navigation, default, android

When you open a link to do navigating or look up something on a map, Android OS asks what application you would like to use to complete the operation. You can make any of these applications the "default" so it doesn't ask you again in the future. Is there a way programmatically retrieve the user's default mapping application?

I want to know how to do this because I will at some point in my app switch the user over to a map and show them a destination. Also the same thing for navigating. I would like to use the program that the user has selected as their default to make them happy.

PS - I would also like to know the answer for iOS/WindowsPhone if anyone knows that too

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way programmatically retrieve the user's default mapping application?

There really isn't such a concept. There may be a default activity for certain `Intent` structures, like `ACTION_VIEW` on a `geo:` `Uri`.

> I will at some point in my app switch the user over to a map and show them a destination

Call `startActivity()` on an `Intent`, set for `ACTION_VIEW` of a `geo:` `Uri` for the destination, and Android will handle it from there. If the user has set a default for that, the user will be taken there. If the user has not set a default, and the user has multiple activities that can handle it, the user will be presented with a chooser. And so forth.

> I would also like to know the answer for iOS/WindowsPhone if anyone knows that too

You will have far better luck if you ask two separate questions for that, customized for those platforms, and with appropriate tags for those platforms.